# Is there any reason to use torchvision.Compose over torch.nn.Sequential?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

The [torchvision.transforms](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html) documentation mentions `torch.nn.Sequential` and [`Compose`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Compose.html#torchvision.transforms.Compose) in the same sentence. They seem to fulfill the same purpose: Combining torchvision transforms.

> In order to script the transformations, please use torch.nn.Sequential instead of Compose.

Is there any reason why one should not always favor `Sequential` over `Compose`?
I find it suspicious that `Compose` exists but has no justification, so I must be missing some important detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works with `Compose` but not with `Sequential`:

```py
transform = torch.nn.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.CenterCrop((512,512))])
```

When using `Sequential`, you'd get the error

```
\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 596, in add_module
    raise TypeError("{} is not a Module subclass".format(
TypeError: torchvision.transforms.transforms.ToTensor is not a Module subclass
```

I conclude that `torch.nn.Sequential` only works with subclasses of `torch.nn.Module`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As was pointed out in the comments, this does not answer the original question.

Yes, there is a good reason not to use `Compose`. Relevant lines from the documentation are

```
This transform does not support torchscript.
```

```
In order to script the transformations, use torch.nn.Sequential
```

What does this mean? [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/Intro_to_TorchScript_tutorial.html) defines an intermediate representation for a PyTorch model. In short, this intermediate representation is a serialized `nn.Module`, containing all weights and control flows.
That is, it contains all necessary information to execute a model. Compare this to workng with a `.pt` file containing a `state_dict`, you need access to the python source to initialize and run anything. Scripting is the act of
serializing a model to a TorchScript representation. This is useful in cases you want to run PyTorch models outside Python, and is also commonly used for conversions to other ML frameworks.

The documentation is trying to say that if you use `Compose` and serialize (script) the model to TorchScript, the resulting model will **not** work correctly. This is an important consideration if you're planning to
deploy PyTorch trained models using ONNX or tensorflow at a later stage.

As to why this exists, my guess is that developers of TorchScript decided that `nn.Sequential` is sufficient and did not see a reason to implement support for `Compose`, but torchvision developers haven't removed the module for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are answering the opposite of what I asked, but the last sentence sounds like the reason `Compose` exists is that it is older than `nn.Sequential`. Is that the sole reason? My question was whether there is a scenario in which I would want to use `Compose`.

Comment: @lucidbrot Oh yeah, seems I completely misunderstood you. Sorry about that. Regarding the actual question, no idea.